# ModuleNotFoundError: 'sklearn' in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv

Using Conda (4.8) on pyhthon 3.7, on Win10. I have scikit learn installed using conda `conda install scikit-learn` .  Tried a few things: also installed it in the env `conda install -n my_env scikit-learn`.  Also tried installing `conda install -c anaconda ipython` - nothing has worked.

I can list it:

```
scikit-learn              0.22             py37h6288b17_0
```

But in juypter notebook get error
`from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_pairs` (tried couple other commands too)
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'**

*But If I use Anaconda UI Navigator to launch notebook everything works fine*

**Update**
I tried this command line option did not work for me, despite plenty effort and  help & support from the community (as below). Meanwhile the Jupyter notebook can also be launched from the Anaconda UI itself. That always was working for me - no configuration or setup needed *(none)*. I have not found any limitations etc with this yet (and you do get the exact same notebook). For advanced/unique use cases where you may need to fine tune your configuration cmd line could be helpful, I am not there.

Comment: [does this help](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)? Specifically: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv`

Comment: @warped This is somewhat all over the place - cant figure out what exactly to be done. Do I re-install pip using conda ` source activate myenv  
conda install pip  
conda install ipykernel`

Comment: Tried `No module named ipykernel`. So I installed ipykernel `conda install ipykernel` - still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, you are loading the wrong kernel when you start your notebook.
Here is a barebones way to set up the environment:

```
conda create -n testenv python=3.7 -y

conda activate testenv

conda install scikit-learn
conda install ipython
conda install notebook

python -m ipykernel install --user --name testenv
```

When you click on `new` in the browser you will have an additional option next to python3, namely the kernel you just registered. I just tested this with anaconda 4.7 and I could import sklearn.

#### edit:

The code in the answer creates a new python environment. Then, it installs ipython and jupyter notebook in that environment and makes sure that this environment can be used with jupyter notebook (i.e. registering the ipykernel).

Now of course besides scikit learn, no other libraries have been installed within that specific environment.

So, if you want to use more libraries, you have to go to the command line, activate the environment, and install the libraries you want to use:

```
conda activate testenv
conda install scipy numpy matplotlib
```

To then run jupyter notebook from the environment, after you have installed all the things you want (and after having closed the command prompt or having deactivated the environment), you can do

```
conda activate testenv
jupyter notebook
```

in the command prompt.

Comment: I had used pip to install my jupyter notebook `pip install jupyterlab`. I only have one python 3.7 so I had created myenv without the python flag. I can do above if that is what that needs to solve the issue,

Comment: Doing these series of steps - essentially **re-install with these steps worked.** Perhaps using `conda install notebook` rather than pip may be the trick.

Comment: After all that - everything has fallen apart - **does not work anymore.**  Nothing should have changed in my env, I am activating and using the same "testenv" - but it no longer works. Now when I create a new notebook - I get choice to pick the env - I choose "testenv". But alas

Comment: Tried Python 3 also does not work, cant find `pandas` module itself.

Comment: So you suggesting I have to install all libraries in each environment. Is that how it is meant to work. So in future I need any more libraries - I have to install. Sort of does not make sense this should not be that difficult- I have all the libraries installed - my not be in the env. Originally I had this library problem (before sklearn) - then I just created **a** environment - that problem went away (I did not have to install any lib in the env). But sklearn issue surfaced in next step. We solved sklearn issue but the old issue resurfaced. One step forward one step back.

Comment: Well you can just work in one environment and install everything into that if you want to. The idea behind having multiple is that you can work on different projects that require different versions of different libraries.

Comment: My point was I did not install anything in my environment originally and everything worked (except sklearn). So what is the issue. See some comments below, probably my issue could be version of jupyter I am pointing. If I run `where jupyter`     `C:\apps\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe`   - likely due to multiple jupyter installs.

Answer (score 1):

Jupyterlab would usually use the environment inside which you launch it. For example:

1. If you activate `my_env` first and then do `jupyter lab` from terminal, it should detect the environment.
2. Incase it fails, go to `Kernel -> Change Kernel` and select the kernel you want to use.

**Note:** While creating a new kernel, I always use the `display-name` parameter which helps. You can do something like:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display-name "Python (my_env)"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this did not work-  Same error  `conda create -n testenv python=3.7 -y`  
`conda activate testenv`  
`conda install ipykernel`  
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name testenv --display-name "Python (testenv)"`  
`jupyter notebook`

Comment: added 1 more step `conda install scikit-learn` - did not help

Comment: One more step and **it worked** `conda install notebook`

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, you need to manually install this package in **Anaconda**.

How do I install? Open your **Anaconda Prompt** and run the below command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

Then restart **Jupyter Notebook** and import this package.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the environment is not activated. Try `conda activate my_env` first, and then type `jupyter notebook`.

The first thing you can do is:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Check if `/path/to/anaconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages` exists in the path.

I find it useful to print the current `sys.path` so that I know where it is looking at.

Comment: I was in my active environment, tried this I have C:\\Users\\sbaha\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',  
 'c:\\apps\\python\\lib\\site-packages',    'c:\\apps\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32' , 'c:\\apps\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',   'c:\\apps\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',   'c:\\apps\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 
  'C:\\Users\\sbaha\\.ipython'

Comment: @Sam-T That's strange, it seems anaconda environment is not in your ``path``. You can type the ``where jupyter`` command in the cmd to see which ``jupyter`` file is used. Then open that file (just a text file), check the first line and you can see the python interpreter used.

Comment: anaconda is in PATH- I did not paste all of it above. `where jupyter`  
`C:\apps\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe` . This is a exe file - cant open it

Comment: I think you start the wrong ``jupyter``. It should be ``/path/to/anaconda/envs/my_env/Scripts`` or something alike. The point is, your ``jupyter`` is not the ``jupyter`` installed by anaconda. You can go to the anaconda path and find the correct ``jupyter``. Still, I think your anaconda is not correctly activated.

Comment: I have installed notebook multiple ways - pip and conda- so not sure where what. How do I fix. My anaconda UI works perfectly. But the command line is where all the problems are - should I even use command line?

Comment: I do have this directory in my system `/path/to/anaconda/envs/my_env/Scripts` - why does my active env not point to it. What is even the purpose of the active env.

Comment: Maybe you should use the UI, I think you are not familiar with command line. conda needs some setup scripts. For example, ``source path/to/anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`` for linux.

Comment: Yeah my UI works perfect, did not have to do anything at all to make it work (not aware of any limitations?)- in the end you get the exact same notebook in which you work. So using UI would absolutely work for me. I am new to conda, nonetheless still confused - why command line does not work - I have **everything installed** in my active env - it somehow still is doing something else and cant find the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda info --envs
```

## when testEnv exists:

```
conda activate testEnv

conda list scikit-learn
```

Comment: extra info: it happened to me using command ine that i made type errors and accidentally created a new environment. So checking with "conda info --envs" helps

Comment: Also: scikit-learn is in the default (base) of the latest anaconda release. So, you may first try to start a notebook from there: => jupyter notebook <enter>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).